# php preg_replace returning null

Tags: php, regex

I'm pretty sure this is some stupid mistake from me but i haven't been able to debug where the error in this lies.

I'm trying to change image paths in html file with this regexp.
It should work, but preg_replace is just returning null time after time.

```
preg_replace("(src=){1}([\"']){1}(.*)([\/]+)(.*[\"']{1})", '/my/path'.$5 , $source);
```

anyone care to lend a hand please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a lot going on here.

1. `/(src=){1}/` is the same as `/src=/`
2. `.*` probably isn't doing what you expect, as it matches a blank string (and is set to be greedy)
3. You are concatenating `$5` to a string, but $5 will not be set in PHP; you probably meant '/my/path$5'

Really though, if you're trying to pull the `src` attribute out of an HTML (or XML) tag, you should be using the [DOM](https://www.php.net/dom). Refer to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: I'm supposed to change paths of all images in a html file.
So the filename itself should stay the same while only the path should change. I thought this would be nice n' easy with regex.
quess not..

Answer (score 3):

You should look at preg_last_error() after you've run into such an error.

More information is available here: http://www.pelagodesign.com/blog/2008/01/25/wtf-preg_replace-returns-null/ or on http://www.php.net/preg_last_error

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your pattern has a lot of unnecessary complications, try this:</strike>

```
preg_replace('#src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"]#", '/my/path$1', $source);
```

if you know you'll only be seeing double quotes, it's even neater:

```
preg_replace('#src="(.*?)"#", '/my/path$1', $source);
```

**EDIT**

Reading your comments maybe you want this?

```
preg_replace('#(<img\s*.*src=")#', '$1/my/path/', $source);
```

Comment: Can't even get this to work. Still returning null. Same effect with preg_grep function.
I'm totally lost here.

Comment: it's closer, but i need to change image paths (like http://www.example.com/image.jpg) to absolute path on my server (like /var/path/image.jpg) for all images in this html document.
so that's why i need all filenames from src attribute.

Comment: oh yeah that worked otherwise ty :) so it's clearly a failure in my regex.